# discord.js: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'toJSON')

Tags: javascript, json, discord.js, to-json

###### Hello,

I was trying to make a bot with discord.js, and following the tutorial at https://discordjs.guide.

And apparently data.toJSON() wasn't recognized (even though builders are installed)

deploy-commands.js:

```js
const { REST } = require('@discordjs/rest');
const { Routes } = require('discord-api-types/v9');
const { token, clientId, guildId } = require('./config.json');
const fs = require('node:fs');

const commands = [];
const commandFiles = fs.readdirSync('./commands').filter(file => file.endsWith('.js'));

for (const file of commandFiles) {
    const command = require(`./commands/${file}`);
    commands.push(command.data.toJSON()); // error here
}

const rest = new REST({ version: '9' }).setToken(token);

(async () => {
    try {
        console.log('Started refreshing application (/) commands.');

        await rest.put(
            Routes.applicationGuildCommands(clientId, guildId),
            { body: commands },
        );

        console.log('Successfully reloaded application (/) commands.');
    }
    catch (error) {
        console.error(error);
    }
})();
```

[[image]]

Comment: The error message says that `command.data` is `undefined`. Why do you think `command.data` should be defined? You haven't shown us what is in any of the files listed in `commandFiles` that you are requiring. Please read [ask] and provide a [mcve].

Comment: You will need to check every file inside your `commands` folder and make sure that every exported object has a `data` property.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had some empty files in my commands folder that were getting read without a data property. I deleted them to solve the problem.